# Post on wall, but i don't see any attachment. Why?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, facebook

Why don't I see  @"The Facebook Running app" caption ? I use the facebook connect sample.

```
-(IBAction)publishStream:(id)sender {
       SBJSON *jsonWriter = [[SBJSON new] autorelease];

  NSDictionary* actionLinks = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"Always Running",@"text",@"http://itsti.me/",@"href", nil], nil];

  NSString *actionLinksStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:actionLinks];   
  NSDictionary* attachment = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                               @"a long run", @"name",
                               @"The Facebook Running app", @"caption",
                               @"it is fun", @"description",
                               @"http://itsti.me/", @"href", nil];   
  NSString *attachmentStr = [jsonWriter stringWithObject:attachment];   
  NSMutableDictionary* params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                 @"Head",  @"user_message_prompt",
                                 actionLinksStr, @"action_links",
                                 attachmentStr, @"attachment",
                                 nil];

  [_facebook dialog:@"feed"
          andParams:params
        andDelegate:self]; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I commented out the action links and attachment parts in the demo & the call to _facebook dialog works just the same. I don't think a call to the dialog is using those parts. I'm in the source code now having a look because there's a current facebook dialog problem out there.

Comment: if you are already answering an old question, why not give some more information about it? you have not really answered anything, only notified that you are still looking for an answer.